# should adding or removing components trigger a repaint?

Tags: forms, repaint, codenameone

Adding or removing components from an active Form does not seem to
automatically trigger a repaint.

When removing a component, the image of the removed component just hangs around.

When adding a new component to an existing form, the setVisible(true) 
does not trigger a repaint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't.

We allow things like `animateLayout` which wouldn't work if we implicitly repainted as you would see a flickering. Also if you remove many components or add many components you'd want to combine this into a single repaint rather than overload the system with tasks.

Comment: I haven't looked into animateLayout, I'll put it into my 2do list, but if I'm not using it, it's obviously incorrect to leave the window's image, and worse to not expose a new window's image.  Perhaps animateLayout should be integrated and coupled with setVisible.     The contract of "repaint" is to repaint sometime soon, not immediately, so adding/removing multiple items shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: This is already there. Repaint doesn't repaint immediately. However, every bit of logic you add to help means the CPU needs to do work... This might not be a big deal in a desktop class CPU but its a huge deal in a mobile CPU. The fact that you can animate everything dynamically thanks to this thing (that also saves CPU usage) is really important on mobile. Try this, instead of `revalidate()` to apply layout, just use `animateLayout(500)`... Whoosh.

Comment: For the record. `animateLayout()` is a `ComponentSelector` method. This Class may prove useful as well for another question I have opened. I may use it to obtain an object reference to a UI `Component` in an elegant way, instead of looking at the "CodeRAD" project.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259140/reference-retrieval-of-a-buttongroup-instance