# Reference retrieval of a ButtonGroup instance

Tags: codenameone

I have created an instance of ButtonGroup and associated that to two RadioButtons. The RadioButtons are added to a Container and the Container added to a Form screen. When the "Back" button is pressed, I want to clear the ButtonGroup selection and reset certain variable instances.
I want to place the code in the ActionListener I have made for the "Back" function. My question is how to retrieve the reference of the ButtonGroup in order to clearSelection()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking at `animateLayout()` method of `ComponentSelector` for another issue that I had, I realized that I may use this Class to obtain `Component` object references jQuery style elegantly. Very powerful and useful concept for codename one.
[should adding or removing components trigger a repaint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689375/should-adding-or-removing-components-trigger-a-repaint/34690156#comment120707938_34690156)

Answer (score 0):

Generally we recommend recreating the `Form` instead of caching it if you intend to "reset it" so I'd avoid this.

If you still want to go in this direction check out `getButtonGroup()` in `RadioButton`. You can also set a new group with the setter method.

You can use `setUnselectAllowed(true)` then invoke `setSelected(false)` on both buttons. Then restore default selection behavior using `setUnselectAllowed(false)`.

Comment: Dear Shai, thank you for your suggestions. I will look into it.
I also took the time to reflect a bit upon the question. I am thinking about obtaining the reference through the ActionEvent object. Perhaps using `getComponent()` or `getSource()`. Then, I am inclined to use `getButtonGroup()`, perhaps as soon as I manage to obtain the correct object reference, because the "Back" context is the `Form` the event was triggered from.
What do you think?

Comment: I just usually do `button.addActionListener(e -> setRadioState(...));`

Comment: I am trying to program with maintainability and performance in mind, and in some cases the two collide.
What logic do you suggest to place in the `ActionListener` lambda? For which case?

I am looking for the most elegant way to acquire the `ButtonGroup` object reference and `clearSelection()` to reset the `ButtonGroup` when navigating "Back" to the previous `Form`, possibly in one line...

However, I have made performance oriented architectural decisions which impede certain common concepts due to those decisions made and maintainability considerations.

Comment: E.g. the "Back" `Command` is set in one place and reused by all `Form` screen objects obliging me to add conditional code to check whether the "from" and "to" `Form` match the specific case before resetting the specific `ButtonGroup`.

Comment: In that case you might find CodeRAD more "elegant" than pure Codename One github.com/shannah/CodeRAD version 2 is coming out soon

Comment: Ok @Shai. Thanks for the recommendation. For the moment I will stick to Codename One though.